# How to find the first signs of the decade Luxon?

Tags: javascript, luxon

Luxon has start of day, year, etc., but how to find the first day of the decade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code to achieve your purpose:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const {
    DateTime
  } = luxon;

  // Get the current DateTime
  const now = DateTime.local();

  // Calculate the first year of the decade
  const firstYearOfDecade = now.year - (now.year % 10);

  // Create a new DateTime object with the first year of the decade, first month, and first day
  const firstDayOfDecade = DateTime.local(firstYearOfDecade, 1, 1);

  // You can use it print whatever you like
  console.log(`${firstDayOfDecade.toISODate()} - ${firstDayOfDecade.weekdayLong}`);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.4.4/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-dUlSLLkxslGILhPdCkALwk4szPhp3xmZIKFtlUD+O9Lslq41Aksmdt5OGqpomDoT4FsCUH70jQU8ezZHI3v1RQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

By using this code.

```
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
const currentDate = DateTime.now();
const firstDayOfDecade = currentDate.startOf("decade");

console.log("First day of the decade:", firstDayOfDecade.toISODate());`
```